# select * from table where column in (sub query) where sub query return ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ora-00904

The query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM MY_TABLE
```

Return

> ORA-00904 Invalid identifier because there is no COLUMN_NAME column in MY_TABLE, so far so good.

The query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OTHER_TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM MY_TABLE)
```

Not only does it not fail, it returns the complete OTHER_TABLE. It happens only when the inside query select for column that is in the “outside” table.

If I run the same query, and just change the inside query select column to different column that also does not exists in the table but does not exists in the table in the outside table as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OTHER_TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (SELECT DIFFERENT_NAME FROM MY_TABLE)
```

`DIFFERENT_NAME` column does not exists in OTHER_TABLE

It does fail on ORA-00904 Invalid identifier.
1.  How come the query that use a column that exists in the outside query but does not exists in the inside query does not fail?
2.  How come it returns the complete table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use columns from the "outer" table in the query in the `in` clause. For each row from the outer table, the value of that row's `column_name` is selected form the inner table (similar to if you were selecting a literal value). Since it's just the same `column_name` value of the row from the outer query, they are obviously equal, so the condition is fulfilled and the row is returned.

A good defensive practice to avoid such mistakes is to fully qualify the columns you're querying (preferably using table aliases), so the query would error out instead of returning something you don't expect:

```
SELECT *
FROM   other_table ot
WHERE  ot.column_name IN (SELECT mt.column_name -- causes error!
                          FROM   my_table mt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that we have two tables: `TA` with field `A` and `TB` with field `B`, now let's write some queries:

```
  select A   -- wrong: TB doesn't have A field
    from TB
```

But this one will be **OK** and return the entire `TB` table providing that `B` field is not null and `TA` is not empty:

```
  select *
    from TB 
   where B in (select B   -- <- B is from TB in both cases
                 from TA)
```

In this case you have

```
  where B in (select B from TA)
```

be equal to

```
  -- 1. null in (...) is null, not true
  -- 2. we have not empty TA 
  where (B is not null) and Exists (select 1 from TA)
```

And, finally

```
  select *
    from TB 
   where B in (select C   -- wrong: there's no field C in TB as well as in TA
                 from TA)
```